# Android studio doesn't recognize UTF-8 encoding

Tags: android, encoding

The problem is that when I use `UTF-8` characters like `ā, ē, š` Android Studio translates them to some different symbols.
This is `Log.d()` that I'm passing:

```
Log.d("Test", "ššāā");
```

The result that I get is

```
D/Test: ЕЎЕЎДЃДЃ
```

And that is not only for `Logcat`. It passes same thing everywhere I try to use these characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your gradle file for any encodings like

```
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251'
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:
`File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings`, then search for `"File Encodings"`, change Project Encoding to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the below are set to UTF-8:

- Global Encoding (Settings > Editor > File Encodings)
- Project Encoding (Settings > Editor > File Encodings)
- Default encoding for properties files (Settings > Editor > File Encodings)
- The actual file encoding [image] at the bottom right in Android Studio